# why serialization proxy pattern is not compatible with classes whose object graph contains circularities

Tags: java, serialization

I read 《Effective Java》and I was told that Serialization Proxy Pattern is not compatible with classes whose object graph contains circularities. Actually I don't get it. So I wrote a sample to validate it. As you see:

```
public class A implements Serializable{
    private B b;

    public A(){
    }

    public A(B b){
            this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B implements Serializable{
    private A a;

    public B(){
    }

    public B(A a){
            this.a = a;
    }
}

public class C implements Serializable{
private A a;
private B b;

public C(A a, B b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}   

private Object writeReplace(){
    return new SerializationProxy(this);
}

private Object readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws InvalidObjectException{
    throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy Required!");
}

private static final class SerializationProxy implements Serializable{
    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    SerializationProxy(C c){
        this.a = c.a;
        this.b = c.b;
    }

    private Object readResolve(){
        return new C(a, b);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    C c = new C(new A(), new B());

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    out.writeObject(c);

    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

    c = (C)in.readObject();
}
}
```

However, it executed very well. So, can anyone explain it further to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What reason did the book give?

Comment: @EJP:It explained that "if you attempt to invoke a method on an object from within its serialization proxy’s readResolve method, you’ll get a ClassCastException, as you don’t have the object yet, only its serialization proxy."

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with circular references generally but with specific situation when
you have a reference to the root object inside your object graph. 
In the following example Container has a list of Items but every item in the list has
a reference to the Container (root object in the object graph!) as it's parent.

If you execute this code, the output will be ClassCastException's stack trace.
But if you comment the line *item.setParent(this);* from the Container's item setter
and runs the code again, output will be fine.

Reason why it happens is the way of implementation of the serialization using writeReplace(). When you
replace original object with SerializationProxy then in the SerializationProxy's stream, 
JVM will replace any reference to the orginal object with a reference to the SerializationProxy
object. (I don't know why it is implemented that way but it is).
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5903

In our case, we put the items in the SerializationProxy object, but items had a reference to the
original object (their parent).
Then when you want to deserialize a stream, deserialized SerializationProxy's reference is 
assigned to the orginal object's reference in the Item's parent field and you have 
a ClassCastException.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Container c = new Container("Circular References Test");
            c.addItem(new Item("Item 1"));
            c.addItem(new Item("Item 2"));

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            out.writeObject(c);

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

            c = (Container)in.readObject();
            System.out.println("Container c has label '" + c.getLabel() + "' and has " + c.getItems().size() + " items.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class Container implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private String label = "";

    public Container() {
    }

    public Container(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean addItem(Item item) {
        if(item != null) {
            item.setParent(this);
            return this.items.add(item);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean removeItem(Item item) {
        if(item != null) {
            item.setParent(null);
            return this.items.remove(item);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return new ArrayList<Item>(this.items);
    }

    private static final class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String containerLabel = "";
        private List<Item> items;
        public SerializationProxy(Container c){
            this.containerLabel = c.getLabel();
            this.items = new ArrayList<>(c.getItems());
        }

        private Object readResolve(){
            Container c = new Container(this.containerLabel);
            for(int i = 0; this.items != null && i < this.items.size(); i++) {
                c.addItem(this.items.get(i));
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    private Object writeReplace(){
        return new SerializationProxy(this);
    }

    private Object readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws InvalidObjectException{
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy Required!");
    }
}

class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Container parent = null;
    private String name = "";

    public Item() { 
    }
    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Container getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Container parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the author of book has an implied meaning.

if we want to invoke a method on an object from within its serialization proxy’s readResolve method, SerializationProxy instance have to hold a reference to proxied instance. once you do that, there is a circularity.

```
    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 122L;
    
    private final Date start;
    private final Date end;
    private Period sp;//have to hold a reference to proxied instance
    
    SerializationProxy(Period p){
        this.start = p.start;
        this.end = p.end;
        this.sp = p;//comment out this line then no ClassCastException
    }
    
    private Object readResolve() {
        //sp.xx() call method of proxied instance
        return new Period(start, end);
    }
}
```

when do deserialization, exception occur:

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of Period$SerializationProxy to field Period$SerializationProxy.sp of type Period in instance of Period$SerializationProxy

the reason is described by Mladen.